# Checking which polygon a set of coordinates lie inside

Tags: python, performance, time-limit-exceeded, pandas, geospatial

I have a massive set of latitude, longitude pairs. I also have a list of [GeoJson](https://geojson.org/) formatted locations. I want to find out which location each pair of coordinates lies in.

I have some code to do this, but it's super slow and won't work against my dataset in it's current format:

```
# Load Dataset
CHICAGO_CRIME = '/content/drive/My Drive/CA683_Assignment_Additional/2010-crime.csv' 
CHICAGO_COMMUNITY_AREAS = '/content/drive/My Drive/CA683_Assignment_Additional/Boundaries - Community Areas (current).geojson'

# Load crime data-set
crime_df = pd.read_csv(CHICAGO_CRIME, parse_dates=True)

# Load community areas
with open(CHICAGO_COMMUNITY_AREAS) as f:
    chicago_community_areas = json.load(f)

# Store polygon objects
for feature in chicago_community_areas['features']:
    feature['polygon'] = (shape(feature['geometry']))

def find_community_area(point):
  closest_point_distance = float('inf')
  closest_ward = None
  # check each polygon to see if it contains the point
  for feature in chicago_community_areas['features']:
      polygon = feature['polygon']

      # Return the name associated with this polygon
      if polygon.contains(point):
          return feature['properties']['area_numbe']

  # If we get here, we couldn't find the point
  # Get the closest one
  for feature in chicago_community_areas['features']:
      polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])

      # Returns a tuple, we only want the first value
      closest_point, p2 = nearest_points(polygon, point)

      point_distance = closest_point.distance(point)

      if point_distance < closest_point_distance:
        closest_point_distance = point_distance
        closest_ward = feature['properties']['area_numbe']

  return closest_ward

# %%timeit
community_areas = []
for index, row in crime_df.iterrows():
  community_area = find_community_area(row["point"])
  community_areas.append(community_area)

# 1 loop, best of 3: 503 ms per loop
```

---

*Note*: These are only for additional information, they are not for review.

At first I tried a couple of ways to solve this, however they were super slow.
Whilst my current code is better I'm still not happy with the performance.

```py
%%timeit
crime_df['community'] = crime_df.apply(lambda x:find_community_area(Point(x.Longitude, x.Latitude)), axis=1)

1 loop, best of 3: 1.62 s per loop
```

```py
%%timeit
community_areas = []
for index, row in crime_df.iterrows():
  community_area = find_community_area(Point(row["Longitude"],row["Latitude"]))
  community_areas.append(community_area)

1 loop, best of 3: 1.64 s per loop
```

Additionally when trying to improve performance I ran into some errors. The above code *works as intended*, only these endeavors failed.
I tried to vectorize the process:

```py
%%timeit
# Vectorized implementation 
crime_df['community'] = find_community_area(crime_df['point'].values)

     16     def _validate(self, ob, stop_prepared=False):
---> 17         if ob is None or ob._geom is None:
     18             raise ValueError("Null geometry supports no operations")
     19         if stop_prepared and hasattr(ob, 'prepared'):

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_geom'
```

I tried using `GeoDataFrame`:

```py
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(crime_df, geometry = geopandas.points_from_xy(crime_df.Longitude, crime_df.Latitude))

crime_df['community'] = find_community_area(gdf.geometry.values)

AttributeError: 'GeometryArray' object has no attribute '_geom'
```

---

Can the performance of my code be improved?

**Format of data**

[Source Data](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-Map/dfnk-7re6) (warning, very very large, approx 7 million samples):

```
Date    Block   IUCR    Primary Type    Description Location Description    Arrest  Domestic    Beat    Ward    FBI Code    X Coordinate    Y Coordinate    Year    Latitude    Longitude   Location
6/19/2015 13:00 029XX W DEVON AVE   810 THEFT   OVER $500   PARKING LOT/GARAGE(NON.RESID.)  FALSE   FALSE   2412    50  6   1155359 1942303 2015    41.99748655 -87.70384887    (41.997486552, -87.70384887)
6/19/2015 16:55 011XX W PRATT BLVD  460 BATTERY SIMPLE  RESIDENCE PORCH/HALLWAY FALSE   FALSE   2432    49  08B 1167327 1945336 2015    42.00555929 -87.65973545    (42.005559291, -87.659735453)
6/18/2015 18:30 064XX S HONORE ST   820 THEFT   $500 AND UNDER  RESIDENCE   FALSE   TRUE    726 15  6   1165122 1861901 2015    41.77665465 -87.67022008    (41.776654652, -87.670220081)
```

[Community Area Data](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Community-Areas-current-/cauq-8yn6):

Shared gist [here](https://gist.github.com/TomSelleck/73da640de2b9dbce9b6a878a7c8834e3) as it's very large.

Comment: Could you show some examples of the data that you are processing?

Comment: @Reinderien IMO your edit only harms the readability of the post.

Comment: @Reinderien Updated post

Comment: I disagree, considering some of the highlighted text is not actually code at all. But, shrug.

Comment: @Reinderien I fail to see how the benefit of not highlighting a couple of numbers outweigh the benefit of highlighting the _Python code_. The code is illegible to me without the syntax highlighting, but some pretty numbers don't matter.

Comment: Why has the community area data been shared on gist when it is also hosted by the City of Chicago? Did you process it somehow?

Comment: Nope no processing, just wanted to share the raw json without forcing you to download it

Comment: Looking at the website, they offer exports in CSV and JSON, etc., but none of those resemble the sample you have shown, which seems to be missing any delimiters.

Comment: That sample copied into the editor as tab-delimited, it should be comma delimited

Comment: How fast does it need to be?  7M records in 500ms doesn't leave much room for improvement.  Each lookup is independent, so you could try the multiprocessing library to take advantage of multiple cores.  Can you do the calculations once and save the results to a local database/file?  Then periodically add new crimes to the local file/database.

Comment: @RootTwo It's 500ms a loop, not for 7M records :(

Comment: @TomSelleck The `%%timeit` magic times execution of the entire cell, so at the end of the first code block, it looks like it times the entire for-loop, which includes processing all of `crime_df`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - thanks. The times I have are for a tiny subset of the whole dataset so the question still stands

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to replace this:

```
  for feature in chicago_community_areas['features']:
      polygon = feature['polygon']

      # Return the name associated with this polygon
      if polygon.contains(point):
          return feature['properties']['area_numbe']
```

with a fundamentally different algorithm. The loop above is O(n), which is - as you have noticed - impractical for the quantity of data you need to process. You need a [spatial index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index) to reduce the time complexity of this lookup to be sublinear. For Python in particular, there is [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/), although I have not tried it so cannot speak to its quality or application to your task. This will require some research on your behalf, and I'm afraid that there is no easy answer other than to do a bunch of reading and experimentation.